# Shadow for the shape(triangle) created with pseudo element

Tags: css

I have created a shape by using `:after` and `:before` in CSS. I created a triangle with `:before` and I want to give shadow effect for the whole shape. But triangle is created by using transparency. Normally, it is a rectangle but with transparency it becomes a triangle, so when I am trying to add shadow, the shadow is being added to the rectangle.

If my explanation is complicated, here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ctarimli/uQQhG/3/

In this fiddle, `div a` is the shape that I have created. `Div b` is the shape that I want to show you the attempt that I have made to add shadow. And I prepared `div c` and changed the colors of the pseudo parts to let you to see the pseudo elements easily.

As you see from the fiddle the shadow on the triangle part is not working as I wanted. I know this is normal but I just wonder if there is a solution for this.

I tried to use second :after or :before to add a new pseudo element to create a shadow but I couldn't do that. Also, is it possible to use second `:before` and `:after` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pseudo elemnt and skew.

Then dispatch shadows inside and outside to hide each other where needed :

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LjriC/)**

---

**CSS**

```
#a {
  background: turquoise ;
  margin:1em;
}
#b {
  background: tomato ;
  margin:1em auto;
}
#c {
  background: orange ;
  margin:1em 18%;
}
div {box-shadow:0 0 5px; width:80%;}
div:after {/* after so it comes last */
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:1.4em;/* tune its-height */
  position:relative;/* to move a bit to hide box-shadow of div parent */
  top:5px;
  left:-10px;
  background:white;
  width:30%;/* tune its size */
  box-shadow:
    inset  18px  0 0 white,
    inset 0px -3px white,
    inset 0 0 3px   black;
  transform:skew(45deg);
}
```

---

HTML base :

```
<div id="a">a <br/><!--demo behavior purpose--> A</div> 
<div id="b">b</div>   
<div id="c">c</div>
```